# Twig проверка, минус

Tags: twig, php

Здравствуйте. Есть такая проверка:

```
<?php if (($count_comm - G_LIMIT_COM) > 0): ?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отнять в twig?

Answer (score 1):

?

```
{% if count_comm - G_LIMIT_COM > 0 %}
```